# Using Packer to build Windows Images into Amazon EC2

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, packer

I was after some help / advise, we are looking at using packer to build our windows templates, so we could provision locally on our workstations, also into our private-cloud at work and also our public cloud offering "AWS"

Amazon AMI, have a lot of config regarding the EC2config tools and persistant drivers and enabling rdp post sysprep, etc, etc

Do you know what I need to including in my packer templates for my templates to work in EC2

Also how will these hosts be patched ?

regards

James

Comment: Hi James, 

Not sure exactly what the specific question you're having is, but I'd start by  looking at the [packer AWS builders](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon.html)..

Answer (score 0):

When using packer, normally only apply the basic setting and software as base image.  Adding EC2config tools, persistant drivers and enabling rdp post sysprep, etc, are not bad idea.

As @fmtn07 recommended, go through `packer.io` documents is the starting and to speed the developing, I recommend to go with the open source repository, there are a lot of samples for your reference.

[joefitzgerald/packer-windows](https://github.com/joefitzgerald/packer-windows)